# Should verification emails be processed in the background?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, backgroundworker, delayed-job, resque

Should verification emails be processed / sent in the background using some kind of background job (Resque, Delayed_Job, etc)?

The app does have a tendency to hang until a verification email is sent. However, it only hangs for a split second or two. Don't know if its worth sending over as a background task.

What are your thoughts?

Comment: I've never any need to do this as I don't experience much delay when sending emails.  There is nothing wrong with adding it to a background processor as the user does not need to receive the email instantly. If the delay is only a couple of seconds on a registration form then it could be overkill.  What is your performance like when you disable the email?

Comment: What do you mean, when I disable the email? You mean, disabling sending verification emails? Our app is not live yet btw, so real statistics, I can't really say atm. I just notice that the app hangs for a split or two seconds when a verification email is sent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main thing to keep in mind is that this delay isn't affecting just the current user, it's also affecting other users because it's holding up the Rails process (the exact effects of this will depend on the web server you're using and your setup).

If this application doesn't have a lot of users (and won't in the future) and you don't have any background job processing at the moment, then it may not be worth adding it. Otherwise it's probably a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

If it's a few split seconds then I think that you can live with it. But if it takes longer then you may move it to delayed_job unless your delayed_job is always clogged and you are too much into background jobs. In that case it may take a bit longer to send the email to user and may ruin user experience. Even in that case you could set a higher priority for sending the verification emails.

I have no doubts about the capability of delayed_job and have been personally using it for quite some time now. Even Github recommends it while releasing resque:
https://github.com/blog/542-introducing-resque

`We need a background job system as serious as our web framework. I highly recommend DelayedJob to anyone whose site is not 50% background work.`